# Upgrading AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection from 5.0.1 to 6 throws exception in MapperConfiguration

Tags: automapper, asp.net-core-2.2

We have a ASP.NET Core 2.2 application, and we just migrated to AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection version 6 from 5.0.1
After resolving the breaking changes related to replacing the usages of ResolveUsing and UseValue to use MapFrom, either running the application or the ConfigurationIsValid test, it throws a "Sequence contains no elements" in the MapperConfiguration initialization.
Nothing has changed in terms of how the profiles are injected, we are using the standard service injection that used to work until now:

```
// In startup.cs
services.AddAutoMapper();

 // In mapper unit test
 var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Startup));
 var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(config => 
 config.AddProfiles(assembly)); <- This throws exception now
 mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: Try the [MyGet](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/The-MyGet-build.html) build. Surely there is a workaround, but I need a repro for that.

Comment: Tried the MyGet build and I'm still getting the same error.
I tried several DI intializers, such as  services.AddAutoMapper(), services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly) and services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup)). I can provide a full stack trace to start with.

Comment: No. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Rasetti/9eff59d3466eb8ca75bbced328c98fd1)
This is a vanilla ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application, with AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection version 6. The same code works using 5.0.1

Comment: That looks broken. About the MyGet build. [This](https://myget.org/feed/automapperdev/package/nuget/AutoMapper/8.0.0-ci-01518) is the latest.

Comment: Try a func based resolver instead.

Comment: Regarding the MyGet build, the last one you sent seems to be pointing to AutoMapper 8.0.0, but I'm referencing AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection, not AutoMapper directly. I'm not sure what's broken though, If I copy the sample into the startup.cs file of a new asp.net core 2.2 app it works.

Comment: Yes, the version was not updated. Look at the date.